# Does Karma have an initialization hook?

Tags: hook, karma-runner

Does [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/) (0.12) have a hook which I can use to perform some initialization before running tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With karma 0.10 I've done the following:

- created an `helper.js` file which has been added to the JS list in the karma configuration

  ```
  module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
      ...
      files: [
        // Helping Libraries
        'vendor/jquery.js',
        'helpers/helper.js',
        ...
      ],
      ...
  ```
- the content of the helper is:

  ```
  window.__karma__.loaded = function() {};

  $(function () {
    // do my stuff in here

    // at the end of my stuff start karma:
    window.__karma__.start();
  });
  ```